# Adwords/GoogleAnalytics/BigqueryのLINK設定をしたのですが、Bigqueryにデータが連携されません

Tags: google-bigquery

とあるスマホアプリを開発しているものです。
Analytics360を利用して、以前からBigQueryExportでGA-BQ連携を利用しています。

一週間ほど前に、広告データ(trafficSourceデータ)をBigQueryで扱いたいのでGAにて「AdWordsLINK設定・AdWords Linking」を行いましたが、BigQuery側に変化がありません。

あまり情報もなく、困っていますので質問させて頂きました。

Comment: GoogleAnalyticsPremiumはUserが少ないので、なかなか知見は出てこないかもしれません。Googleのサポートなどに連絡した方が良いかも。

Comment: ありがとうございます。サポートに問い合わせるしかなさそうですねー